# Custom Tabs in flutter

Tags: flutter, tabs

How can i create a tab that looks like the design that shows below?
I'm finding it difficult to create the overlapping design for each tab.

[image one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8tg9.png)

[image two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HIoM.png)

I would appreciate some help in designing this in the code it self.

What i try so far is as follows

```
Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: cBackground,
  body:
      Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 16),
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: const Color(0xffDEDFE7), width: 1),
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
              topRight: Radius.circular(14),
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(14),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(14),
            ),
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          width: 1800,
        ),
        ..._tabs,
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

I assign each tab like this

```
Positioned(
  left: 0,
  child: TabletTab(
    onTap: () {},
    key: Key('key_here'),
    title: "Title",
    iconPath: Icons.fire,
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create custom widget, add your tabs in `Stack` and use `Positioned` to configure position of each tab

Comment: i've update the code with what i tried with this similar approach.. I know that it is wrong and need some help with refactoring that.

Comment: Wrong, `Positioned` works only inside `Stack`